# skinning my app consume huge amount of Mb in the native heap (much more that image actual size)

Tags: android, memory, android-image

I use a skin in my app,and load something like 1.5 Mb of images at some of the activities.
This shouldn't be a problem.... 1.5 Mb + default of ~6Mb for the app when loaded... however, things are quite different.
each png I load as a drawable in my layout xmls, is being multiplied by at least 10 from its actual size...., I wrote a sample app with nothing except for a black screen, and loaded it once without anything on it and got native-heap of 5.8Mb, and then loaded it with a small png of 25Kb and guess what.... 6.25Mb.
I loaded my application with nothing but the skin, and it started with 14.5Mb!!!!!!!!

so now I am in the middle of doing a bitmap recycle operation after each and every activity change.

Is this a known issue with android? 
png files are loaded with much bigger size inside the native-heap? 
is there a solution other than my current plan?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNG files (as well as many other image formats, such as JPEG) are compressed files, pretty much similar to zip-files. When you load them into memory they will be uncompressed
and take more space consequently.

How much depends on the internal [image config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html), the default is `ARGB8888`, which takes 4 bytes per pixel. So the memory consumption only depends on the image size, not on the filesize on disk *(which can get pretty small. For example: A 500x500 px bitmap consisting of one color has a good compression ratio)*.

Example for a 500x500 px image is `500*500*4 bytes = 0.954 MB`, which is almost one megabyte.

Comment: so the only available solution for me not getting an out-of-memory is to load&recycle each and every big png when resuming and pausing an activity?

Comment: Apart from lowering their size, yes pretty much. You can also load bitmaps in native code using the ndk, this bypasses the memory limit. But I got no experience with that, try googling around a bit. Also try searching for [android outofmemory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+bitmap+outofmemory+exception), this exception occurs often when people try to allocate too much memory using bitmaps and is well documented (with all the possible solutions to reducing the mem footprint).

Comment: for the last 2 days I've been searching for outofmemory exception.... I think I know it all by heart till now.... :) that's where I figured out I must recycle... thought there might be a better solution without lowering the image resolution (eat the cake and....). Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, though it would be helpful in case you didn't stumble on an exception yet. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: once in a while I get the canvas using recycled image... still not sure why.... I am loading all needed stuff onresume and recycling onpause.... any idea what can cause? I checked 100 times that I recycle & init the same images...

Comment: Not from the top of my head, I'd have to see the code at least. If this persists, open a new question with code and a detailed description. This way other people, who can help, will see it too. Chances that they check a question marked as solved are pretty low.